# How To Create Google Compute Engine Instance Using Fog In Ruby

Tags: ruby, google-compute-engine, fog

I try with following code but i am getting error,

```
server = connection.servers.create({
:name => "instance-#{Time.now}",
:image_name => "debian-7-wheezy-v20150325",
      :machine_type => "f1-micro",
        :zone_name => "us-central1-a",         
})

/home/vijay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/fog-core-1.30.0/lib/fog/core/attributes.rb:151:in `requires': disks is required for this operation (ArgumentError)
from /home/vijay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/fog-1.29.0/lib/fog/google/models/compute/server.rb:218:in `save'
from /home/vijay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/fog-core-1.30.0/lib/fog/core/collection.rb:51:in `create'
from google_compute_engine.rb:11:in `<main>'
```

I think i am missing some parameter which is required, can someone help me to solve this problem.

Comment: drop `-a` from `zone_name`. It should only be `us-central1`

Comment: No, It still not working same error @shivam

Comment: `disks is required for this operation (ArgumentError)` Seems you need to pass :disks arg?

Comment: can you give sample value for arg? @MattDarby

Comment: Everything looks fine, I believe you should add the following parameter in the end:  
server.wait_for { ready? } 
Another way to do it which is equivalent is using the following: 
server = connection.servers.bootstrap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First create a disk:

```
disk = connection.disks.create({
  :name => "my-disk",
  :zone_name => "us-central1-a",
  :size_gb => 10,
  :source_image => "debian-7-wheezy-v20150325"})
```

Next create the instance with that disk:

```
server = connection.servers.create({
  :name => "my-server",
  :machine_type => "f1-micro",
  :zone_name => "us-central1-a",
  :disks => [disk.get_as_boot_disk]})
```

Note you can attach multiple disks at instance creation.

Comment: thanks a lot @Paul it is working. can you suggest any site where i can learn it.

Comment: Take a look at the Fog repo https://github.com/fog/fog-google

In particular https://github.com/fog/fog-google/blob/master/lib/fog/google/models/compute/disk.rb and https://github.com/fog/fog-google/blob/master/lib/fog/google/models/compute/server.rb